# Inline Assembly Procedure Crash When Accessing Arguments

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have the following x86 procedure that I am trying to call from a c program:

```
        PUBLIC _funcf  
_TEXT SEGMENT WORD PUBLIC 'CODE'
_funcf  PROC
    push    EBP
    mov     EBP,    ESP
    sub     ESP,    4                   ; make space for x (4)

    mov     EAX,    DWORD PTR 4[ebp]    ; move v1 into EAX

    ...

    pop     EBP
    ret
_funcf  ENDP

_TEXT   ENDS  
        END
```

which is called as follows:

```
extern "C" int funcf( int32_t v1, int32_t v2, int32_t v3 );

int main( int argc, char *vargs[] )
{

    ...

    output = funcf( v1, v2, v3 );

    ...

}
```

However when run, an access violation is received on the `mov EAX` command. I looked at the memory view using the debugger, and the memory stored at `ebp+4` is the expected argument, so I was confused as to what was causing the crash. I noticed that the memory address given by the access violation was not the same as `ebp+4`, and upon viewing the disassembly of my assembly code, I found that it was being translated into

```
mov         ax,word ptr [di+4]
```

where `di` is pointing to a completely different address, and is the address given by the exception. Is this just a misleading product of the way the disassembly works, or is my code actually being changed to this unexpected operation? Regardless, the source of the crash is unknown to me.

Comment: `mov ax, word ptr [di + 4]` and `mov eax, dword ptr [ebp + 4]` are the 16-bit and 32-bit interpretations, respectively, of the [same instruction bytes](http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/?opcodes=8b+45+04&arch=x86-32&endianness=little#disassembly) `8B 45 04`. Given that the 16-bit interpretation explains the actual access violation, it seems the code is being executed in 16-bit mode. To dig further it would be helpful to know your platform (operating system / environment, and how you are linking and running the program).

Comment: I'm just using Visual Studio 2015 which is using I assume MASM. The platform is set to x86, and the command line for MASM is `ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\procedure.obj" /Fl"" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta`. I'm using Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: `v1` is at `[ebp+8]`, `v2` is at `[ebp+12]`, `v3` is at `[ebp+16]`, so "...DWORD PTR 4[ebp]" is wrong, but can't have caused the crash. Have you thought about adjusting the stack with `add esp, 4`?

Comment: Using the 'Go to Disassembly' feature of the Visual Studio debugger. Did a small amount of googling and can't seem to find a way to tell it whether the code is 16-bit or 32-bit.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not experienced with VS + MASM, but hopefully this points you in the right direction. Operand sizes are governed by the CS register and by override prefixes. If the "d" bit (CS.d) is set, the processor interprets operands as 32-bit instead of 16-bit. In either mode, the operand size prefix byte `0x66` can be given to switch the operand size. So, either your disassembler is wrongly treating the instruction sequence in 16-bit mode (which would not explain the access violation), or you have somehow generated a spurious override, or you're executing in 16-bit context (CS.d = 0).

Comment: Is there more to your assembly file than what you are showing (above the function (like a `.model` directive)

Comment: @rkhb I have tried both `ebp+8` and `ebp+4`. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5sds75we.aspx) uses `ebp+4`, however we learned in my computing course to use `ebp+8`. Wont using `add esp, 4` have the same effect as removing `sub esp, 4`, which makes room for a local variable used in another portion of the procedure?

Comment: @MichaelPetch No, the entire assembly file is shown with the exception of the body of the procedure which only contains some simple `mov` and `add` instructions.

Comment: Given that you don't specify `.model flat` you will likely have to specify it as part of your _TEXT segment: `_TEXT SEGMENT WORD FLAT PUBLIC 'CODE'` I suspect it defaulted to `USE16`

Comment: before `POP EBP` I hope you also have a `mov     ESP,    EBP`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ah, that was it! I did not specify `FLAT` (or I assume `USE32` would work as well). Of course the answer was right there in the docs too, I just ignored it. I also did not include `mov ESP, EBP`, thanks for the tip. Feel free to post as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I'd recommend simplifying things though. Use `.model flat, C` at the top. Then you can remove the `_TEXT` segment altogether. To place code in the code segment you then just use the `.code` directive. By using `C` in the model directive you can then drop the underscore off the function names. So `_funcf  PROC` would become `funcf  PROC`, it would then be `PUBLIC funcf` and `funcf  ENDP` . The `C` on the model will automatically decorate the names with the underscores for you.

Comment: @smoth190: The separate assembly function in the MSDN article is blatantly wrong. Forget it. Now and forever!

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out `SEGMENT` was defaulting to `USE16` instead of `USE32`/`FLAT`, which was causing it to be assembled in 16-bit mode, despite little explanation in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06y3478.aspx).

Also as Michael said, the assembly file can be simplified to:

```
.model flat, C

.code

funcf   PROC
    push    EBP
    mov     EBP,    ESP
    sub     ESP,    4                   ; make space for x (4)

    mov     EAX,    DWORD PTR 8[ebp]    ; move v1 into EAX

    ...

    mov     ESP,    EBP
    pop     EBP
    ret
funcf   ENDP

END
```

in order to simplify integration with the c code.

Comment: I recommend using FLAT instead of USE32 in 32-bit Windows code because there is an implicit `ASSUME CS:FLAT` done when using `FLAT` on a segment which isn't the case for `USE32`. For what you are doing it likely won't make a difference.